# Pass array into SQL to return same array size and order back

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day. I have one table. I am trying to pass an array into sql using visual basic. I am executing my query which is a static list for now and its returning the right amount of rows, but it distorts the data set order.

If one record doesn't exist the case statements returns a 0. If it does exists then it returns the part number. The problem is that it places the dataset out of order listing the ones that exist first and the ones that don't last.

How to perform a case statement against an array of values that will return the same order in which it came in? Any help is most appreciated. Thanks.

Table

```
1   1001
2   1002
3   1003
4   1004
5   1005
6   1006
```

My Query

```
SELECT pkid AS listNum, 
       PartNumber = CASE 
                      WHEN partnumber IN ( 1001, 3, 1003 ) THEN partnumber 
                      ELSE 0 
                    END 
FROM   bindata
```

Undesired Results

```
1   1001
2   1003
3   0
```

Desired Results

```
1   1001
2   0
3   1003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to pass a delimited string and perform a `LEFT JOIN`

**Example**

```
Declare @Search varchar(max) = '1001, 3, 1003 '

Select A.RetSeq
      ,Value  = isnull(partnumber,0)
 From  (
         Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
               ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
         From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@Search,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
         Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
       ) A
 Left Join  YourTable  B
  on  A.RetVal=B.partnumber
 Order By RetSeq
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  Value
1       1001
2       0
3       1003
```

Comment: That was smooth! Thank you!

Comment: @arios Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a string splitter that uses a numbering system that uses row numbers to maintain the original positions of the array items.
[Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) is a prime example...

Assuming that you have the DelimitedSplit8K function, the query looks like this...

```
DECLARE @array VARCHAR(100) = '1001, 3, 1003';

WITH
    cte_split_array AS (
        SELECT 
            dsk.ItemNumber,
            partnumber = CONVERT(INT, dsk.Item)
        FROM
            dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@array, ',') dsk
        )

SELECT 
    partnumber = ISNULL(bd.partnumber , 0)
FROM
    cte_split_array sa
    LEFT JOIN dbo.bindata bd
        ON sa.partnumber = bd.partnumber
ORDER BY 
    sa.partnumber;
```

If for some reason you aren't able or allowed to add the aforementioned function, it can be done without it but it does make for slightly more complex code...

```
DECLARE @array VARCHAR(100) = '1001, 3, 1003';

WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_Tally (n) AS (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@array))
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
            cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b
        ),
    cte_starts AS (
        SELECT 
            n = 1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            t.n + 2
        FROM
            cte_Tally t
        WHERE
            SUBSTRING(@array, t.n, 2) = ', '
        ),
    cte_split_array AS (
        SELECT 
            s.n,
            partnumber = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@array, s.n, LEAD(s.n, 1, 8002) OVER (ORDER BY s.n) - s.n - 2))
        FROM
            cte_starts s
        )
SELECT 
    partnumber = ISNULL(bd.partnumber , 0)
FROM
    cte_split_array sa
    LEFT JOIN dbo.bindata bd
        ON sa.partnumber = bd.partnumber
ORDER BY 
    sa.n;
```

Comment: Haven’t seen you in a while. I used your tally function today. Thanks for that nugget. I also posted it on my git toolbox and credited you fully of course. Sweet function.

Comment: It is a good function but I can't take too much credit for it. To the best of my knowledge, The idea originated with Itzik Ben-Gan. The function I created is just a variation of his. In any case, I'm glad you're able to make good use of it. :D

Answer (score 0):

somehow you have to preserve the order of array before your query, before running your actual query , you can create a temp table:
ordered_array:
row_number pkid

and then join the result with ordered_array and sort on row_number.

Comment: I am trying that as we speak.. its tricky since I am passing a bunch of strings into the query for checking. Thanks

Comment: I dont have much help from my front end developer.. relying strictly on the array coming into sql

Comment: you don't need help from frontend, you can create a temp table and delete it at the end

Comment: problem is  insert into @tbl values ('$array')  doesnt work.  I keep getting the more columns than supplied error. The array is going left to right not top to bottom